# Can I disable the Lion animation when switching to/from fullscreen apps?

Tags: macos, settings, customization

In Lion there is an animation when switching to and from full screen applications. Full screen apps are great, especially on a 11" screen, but this animation is getting very annoying. Is there a way to turn off these animations?

Comment: Can we reopen the question now that it's officially out?

Comment: We are not re-opening Lion questions that were asked before the official release.

Comment: Apparently there is re-post prevention logic and it's smart enough to not allow another question with only minor differences. Can you reopen this?

Comment: Done. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

There is, at least, a way to speed them up with a SIMBL bundle: http://www.yllier.net/SUFSA.html

Comment: It gives me a 404 for the Dropbox URL :(

Comment: I found SpeedUpFullScreenAnimation on this link. (https://sites.google.com/a/oscvi.com/mrplayter2/uploaded-files) But it doesn't work on Mountain Lion. (Lion is not tested)

Answer (score 0):

No..for now there is no way to turn it off. I also want to turn to the annoying animations when a new window appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the system-wide animation for opening new windows in Lion.

http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/26/hackinations-5-really-good-lion-tweaks/

**Turn off zooming windows**

Open Terminal and type the following:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO`

Reboot.

Comment: This doesn't impact the animations when an app is in full screen mode.

Comment: This will not affect the animation the Dakku is asking about. It only disables a very subtle animation that occurs when a new window is opened.

It also does not require a reboot to take effect. Simply run the command like this:

defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO; killall Dock