# Full screen videos in Chrome suffer a lag

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I have an issue concerning full screen videos within the Google Chrome browser. The video lags for a second.
Since it is too hard to explain, [I captured 16 seconds of video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzrxVCsGKt0).

What could be the cause on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the video correctly, it's the long animation you're wondering what is? I don't see any other lag, please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Using the HTML5-version of YouTube, utilizes OS X's built in full screen mode. The animation from single-window to full screen in OS X *is* this slow, and it annoys me as well. Try disabling the HTML5-mode from [here](http://youtube.com/html5), or to shorten and/or remove the full screen animation it alltogether, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17440/16258) and it's answers.

Comment: You're very welcome, and welcome to AskDifferent! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like running it in HTML5-mode fixed the problem for me

Comment: How do you do that?